# create a dynamic editable datatable in a backing bean?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to create a datatable with inputs in a backing bean, but apparently the values are not updated...

JSF code:

```
<h:form id="formTest" >
     <h:panelGroup binding="#{backingAlgoritmo.panelGroup}" />
</h:form>
```

backing bean code:

```
public HtmlPanelGroup getPanelGroup() {


    panelGroup = new HtmlPanelGroup();

    panelGroup.getChildren().add(getDataTableCromossomos());

    HtmlCommandButton saveButton = new HtmlCommandButton();
    saveButton.setId("save"); 
    saveButton.setValue("Save");
    saveButton.setActionExpression(
            createActionExpression("#{algGeneticoBean.executa()}", null));
    panelGroup.getChildren().add(saveButton);

    return panelGroup;

}



public DataTable getDataTableCromossomos() {
    dataTableCromossomos = new DataTable();
    dataTableCromossomos.setValueExpression("value", createValueExpression("#{algGeneticoBean.algoritmo.populacaoInicial.cromossomos}", List.class));
    dataTableCromossomos.setVar("c");

    if (algGeneticoBean != null) {
        int cont = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < algGeneticoBean.getQtdGenes(); i++) {
            Column column = new Column();
            dataTableCromossomos.getChildren().add(column);

            HtmlInputText input = new HtmlInputText();
            input.setValueExpression("value", createValueExpression("#{c.genes.get(" + i + ").valorGeneString}", String.class));
            input.setRequired(true);
            input.setSize(2);
            System.out.println("#{c.genes.get(" + i + ").valorGene}");
            column.getChildren().add(input);


        }
    }

    return dataTableCromossomos;
}
```

The dataTable is created, but when I submit the form, the values are not updated in the bean

I'm using primefaces 3.3.1

Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried using a CommandButton from primefaces API (instead of the JSF HtmlCommandButton), and adding a update="formTest" attribute to it?